# url rewrite with a question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change this url:

```
mydomain. com/?root=yes
```

to: 
    mydomain. com/

I can't figure out how to deal with the question mark.

Comment: You want to redirect or rewrite?

Comment: Why you want to hide all php parameters? What is the point?

Comment: sorry thought I was clear. rewrite.

Comment: I have two instances when someone lands on the page -- my domain. com/?root=yes they click on enter and the url switches to  my domain. com/?root=no I just want to hide those two instances. I can get the rule to run if I try an example without the ? escaping the /? skips the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `?` followed by nothing inside the rewrite rule to indicate that mod_rewrite should clear the query string while rewriting. Example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^root=yes$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php? # index.php will receive an empty querystring
```

Comment: this rule pretty much strips everything? when in place the whole site breaks.

Comment: It removed the query string entirely, yes -- the PHP script receives an empty query string. Is this something you do not want?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['root']) && $_GET['root'] == 'yes')
{
    header('Location: http://mydomain.com');
}
```

Comment: This is PHP, not mod-rewrite.

Comment: why do you think he means mod-rewrite? From the question tags! And what is the first of all tags? PHP.

Comment: The order of the tags is fixed by SO, not by the user. But your code looks okay, so +1 (although I would add a `/` after `.com`).